# 10-fold Cross Validation for Model performance

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cross-validation

I am a newbie in Validating models, I am currently trying to make use of the MATLAB K-fold validation to assess the performance of my polynomial model that predicts house prices. I have 243 samples, i divided them into 10 groups, i then used 'for loop' to test 9 groups against 1 group (repeated X 10) My problem is storing the error rate (performance) for the 10 times i am making the prediction. How do i do that please? I tried making use of 'classperf' but i am getting the following error, Please see my code below;

Data set sample:

```
DateX: 10,20,30,40 ...    
PriceY: 200,250,300,400 ...

% MATLAB code

K = 10;

cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold',DateX,K); %10-folds 
cp = classperf(DateX);   %To store (performance)

for i = 1:K
    testIDx = (cvFolds == i);
    trainIDx = ~testIDx;
    model1 = polyfit(DateX(trainIDx),PriceY(trainIDx),2);
    prediction1=model1(1)*DateX(testIDx).^2+model1(2)*DateX(testIDx)+model1(3);
    cp = classperf(cp,prediction1,testIDx);
end
```

My Error Message:

```
Error using classperf (line 230)
When the class labels of the CP object are numeric, the output
of the classifier must be all non-negative integers or NaN's.
```

Are there any suggestions on how can I store the performance of my model and I would appreciate examples of other methods in MATLAB that I can apply to make predictions and validate performance (Neural networks, Classification e.t.c.)?

Comment: There are some mistakes. 1. Why are you overwriting `cp` in your for loop? 2. Why are you giving `cp` as an input argument to `cp`? If you just want error rate, you can simply do: `myCP=classperf(<<trueLabels>>,prediction1);`. Then say `myCP.errorRate` to get the error rate. What you are trying to do is updating the classifier, if so, then do `cp=classperf(trueLabels)` outside the for loop. Inside the for loop do, `classperf(cp, prediction1, testIdx)`. Then say, `myError(i,1)=cp.errorRate`. Final note: please format the code in the future.

Comment: Thank you @ParagS.Chandakkar I've seen my mistakes now. Although, I am still not getting the right results with the classperf function but i will read more about it and try other methods as well.

Comment: Read the `classperf` documentation carefully. You should be able to get the answer.